# How to make pixel spacing of two images with equal size the same in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel

I've reconstructed a MR image and I have the original image from the scanner. I want to compare these two images which have the same size but different pixel spacing (pixel size). I'm wondering how I can make their pixel size equal?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: pixel size is always in units of pixels. what exactly do you mean? please give a minimal example...

Comment: Are you talking about the physical dimensions of each pixel in the acquisition hardware (i.e. area)? Once you digitize the image, the actual pixel units themselves are unitless.  Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: There are two factors that control the size of an image - the number of pixels along each side (i.e. its pixel dimensions) and the number of pixels per inch that are needed when printing or displaying the image (referred to as `dpi` or `ppi` - dots per inch or pixels per inch). If your two images have the same number of pixels, you most likely need to change the `dpi`. (Yes, I know there is a whole other debate about `dpi` versus `ppi` but I am trying to make it simple)